# Image region/tree detection from google map

Tags: java, image-processing

I am planing to write a **Java** application to identify certain types of trees using google maps . I have knoweldge in google maps api. my problem is how to recognize trees from map. I found some libs like [jjil](http://code.google.com/p/jjil/). But i don't know whether it is useful or not. Can any one give some inputs for this project ?

Comment: The necessary algorithm doesn't sound very simple, maybe it's a job for http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ . Also is there any particular reason why you have to use Java or is it just personal preference?

Comment: @PeterT I have only experience with java.

Comment: Can you post sample image sections of the kinds of trees you want to distinguish?

Answer (score 3):

The general idea would probably be something like this:

1. Collect a large number of positive and negative samples (i.e. images from Google Maps that you want to recognize and ones that you don't want to recognize). It's hard to say how many you'll really need; depending on how similar they are and how many features you need, 100 might be enough or 10000 might be too few.
2. Find a set of texture features. Nobody can tell you what features are optimal without seeing the sample images (1) first.
3. Train a machine learning algorithm (e.g. SVM, neural network). Split the sample set into a training set and a test set to judge the discrimination quality.

Step 1 is just work, and I doubt anyone on Stackoverflow will do it for you. If you have the samples and post them, we might be able to help with steps 2/3, though.